# Python add command in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, command

I wanna add command in "windows" terminal.

Lets say I have this code

```py
def add_command(command, call_function):
  #do something
def print_hello():
  print("hello function")
add_command("hello", print_hello)
```

and here's Windows terminal

```
C:/> python main.py
C:/> hello
hello function
C:/>
```

Like this

Edit: not a python console not other terminals Only WINDOWS terminal

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?

Comment: Please try not to edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run function from terminal:

```
python -c "from main import print_hello; print_hello()"
```

or you can simply add these code at the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_hello()
```

and then run:

```
python main.py
```

or you can call function based on your input:

```
def print_hello():
    print("hello function")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd = input()
    if cmd == "hello":
        print_hello()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install a batch file with the name you want, and have it run Python with parameters.

Assuming `C:\users\you\bat` is in your `PATH`, you can create `C:\users\you\bat\hello.cmd` with contents similar to

```
@echo off
python C:\users\you\python\script.py
```

to make it run the command above when you type `hello` at the CMD prompt.
(There is no reason *per se* to not have it run `python -c "... your entire script here ..."` directly from the `hello.cmd` file if you prefer, though Windows quoting etc makes this rather pesky in practice.)

If your `PATH` doesn't already contain a directory for your own batch files (or similar), probably create a directory for that purpose and add it to your `PATH` first. The answer presupposes that you have one directory for batch files (which should be on your `PATH`) and another for your Python scripts, but this is just a vague, Unix-y convention.

If you want Python to create the file for you, that can be done as well, of course.

```py
with open('C:/users/you/bat/hello.cmd', 'w') as scriptfile:
    scriptfile.write('\n'.join(command for command in
        ('@echo off', r'python C:\users\you\python\script.py', '')))
```

More generally, you can install system-wide command-line scripts via `setup.py` using the `console_scripts` facility; but this is probably something you should revisit only once you have some experience with creating installable Python modules.

Comment: Then How to add .cmd file in PATH on Python?

Comment: The answer already tells you how to do that. I updated it with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to "add commands" that implement Python functionality is through the use of virtual environments and standard Python packaging technology.

If you structure code in a sufficiently disciplined way then for `pip`-based installations you can define so-called [`console_scripts` entry points](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/). If you use `poetry` then you can define entry points in the *pyproject.toml* file's `[tool.poetry.scripts]` section.

When you install your code in a virtualenv the entry point commands become available.

What many people don't realise is (at least under Unix and friends, sorry, my Windows experience is limited) that the files representing each entry point indicate the virtualenv's python executable as the processor, so they can be linked from or copied to other directories and still function correctly.